# Google bigquery export table to multiple files in Google Cloud storage and sometimes one single file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am using Bigquery python libraries to export data from Bigquery tables into GCS in csv format.

I have given a wildcard pattern assuming some tables can be more than 1 GB

Sometimes even though table is few MB it creates multiple files and sometimes just it creates just 1 file.

Is there a logic behind this?

My export workflow is the following:

```
project = bq_project dataset_id = bq_dataset_id table_id = bq_table_id     
bucket_name =bq_bucket_name workflow_name=workflow_nm 
csv_file_nm=workflow_nm+"/"+csv_file_prefix_in_gcs+'*'client = 
bigquery.Client() destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, 
csv_file_nm) dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project) 
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id) destination_table = 
client.get_table(dataset_ref.table(table_id)) configuration = 
bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig() configuration.destination_format='CSV' – 
csv_file_nm=workflow_nm+"/"+csv_file_prefix_in_gcs
```

Comment: wich wildcard are you using? `gs://my-bucket/file-name-*.json` or `gs://my-bucket/file-name-<worker number>-*.json` ?

Comment: project = bq_project
    dataset_id = bq_dataset_id
    table_id = bq_table_id
    bucket_name =bq_bucket_name
    workflow_name=workflow_nm
    csv_file_nm=workflow_nm+"/"+csv_file_prefix_in_gcs+'*'client = bigquery.Client()     
    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, csv_file_nm)
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    destination_table = client.get_table(dataset_ref.table(table_id))
    configuration = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    configuration.destination_format='CSV'

Comment: csv_file_nm=workflow_nm+"/"+csv_file_prefix_in_gcs

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an intended behaviour of the export. The [Bigquery Export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) documentation specifies the following:

> When you export data to multiple files, the size of the files will
>   vary.

This corresponds to the behavior you are seeing in your exports.

Comment: Thank you. But we also see n number of empty files created with just the header records. No Data in them.

Comment: Ok, that is different. Can you please share with us the script that you are running in order to reproduce this? This seems to be a bug

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QxZsiN0whcEFqQkJDuEZfTxvkyl2OQfu

Comment: please see if u r able to access

Comment: I can't find any problem in your code. This may happen depending on the structure of your table. Since .avro files are "more efficiently generated" try to perform the export in this format and tell us if you still see a lot of empty files.

Comment: @sreekanth, there seems a bug in BigQuery exporting which is being fixed. However, it does export some "empty" files without missing data. If your logic always accepts empty exported file, then its behavior will always be correct before or after the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same empty files issue when using EXPORT DATA.

After doing a bit of R&D found the solution. Put LIMIT xxx in your SELECT SQL and it will do the trick.

You can find the count, and put that as LIMIT value.

SELECT ....

FROM ...

WHERE ...

**LIMIT xxx**