# Big query EXPORT DATA statement creating mutiple files with no data and just header record

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have read similar issue here but not able to understand if this is fixed.

[Google bigquery export table to multiple files in Google Cloud storage and sometimes one single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447205/google-bigquery-export-table-to-multiple-files-in-google-cloud-storage-and-somet)

I am using below big query EXPORT DATA OPTIONS to export the data from 2 tables in a file. I have written select query for the same.

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
uri='gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_'||CURRENT_DATE()||'*.csv',
format='CSV',
overwrite=true,
header=true,
field_delimiter='|') AS     
SELECT
```

I have only 2 rows returning from my select query and I assume that only one file should be getting created in google cloud storage. Multiple files are created only when data is more than 1 GB. thats what I understand.

However, 3 files got created in cloud storage where 2 files just had the header record and the third file has 3 records(one header and 2 actual data record)

```
radhika_sharma_ibm@cloudshell:~ (whr-asia-datalake-nonprod)$ gsutil ls gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/
gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/
gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_2021-02-04000000000000.csv
gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_2021-02-04000000000001.csv
gs://whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/Customer_Master_2021-02-04000000000002.csv
```

Why empty files are getting created?
Can anyone please help? We don't want to create empty files. I believe only one file should be created when it is 1 GB. more than 1 GB, we should have multiple files but NOT empty.

Comment: What the total size your your request, even if you have only 2 rows returned?

Comment: hello @guillaumeblaquiere, I was trying jut with test data though total size will be more than 10 GB for one time load and we need to provide csv extract for the same.  However, for incremental load, the csv extract that we need to provide will be few MB's and we don't expect more data. I am ok with multiple files, but it should not be creating empty files right?

Comment: it's the size of the table of your test data that interest me. I think we are in a side effect of the feature, I just would like to understand to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, Could you please let me know what details you need to reproduce this? You can just try exporting a big query with  just10 records using EXPORT utility and see how may files it creates. Ideally it should create only 1 file with all 10 records but its not like that. I am wondering if based on the number of slots used that big query creates multiple export files. Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: It was my assumption: number of slot or file overprovisioning based on the size of the query (volume scanned, not volume returned). It's maybe a side effect of the feature

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere,
I confirm that there is a side effect!! 
The export table executed from the SQL GCP Console  doesn't work as expected even with small data table.
I confirm that there is a side effect!! 
The export table executed from the SQL GCP Console  doesn't work as expected, even with small data table.

Comment: @radhikasharma, I am looking for java api to get the number of files created by "Export Data" Statement. Didn't find any API.
Though in case of "Extract Job", com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobStatistics.getExtract() method returns the instance of JobStatistics4 class which do contain method getDestinationUriFileCounts() to determine number of files created.


public JobStatistics4 getExtract() {
    return extract;
}

Answer (score 11):

You have to force all data to be loaded into one worker. In this way you will be exporting only one file (if <1Gb).
My workaround: add a select distinct * on top of the Select statement.

Comment: Thanks! I just used this workaround, and help me a lot! I'm processing >137Gb, so the process generated more than one file, but fewer than before.

Comment: The distinct * hack worked here! Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't always work. Not sure why

Answer (score 5):

Under the hood, BigQuery utilizes multiple workers to read and process different sections of data and when we use wildcards, each worker would create a separate output file.

Currently BigQuery produces empty files even if no data is returned and thus we get multiple empty files. The Bigquery product team is aware of this issue and they are working to fix this, however there is no ETA which can be shared.

There is a public issue [tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/142979335) that will be updated with periodic progress. You can STAR the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

However for the time being I would like to provide a workaround as follows:

If you know that the output will be less than 1GB,  you can specify a single URI to get a single output file. However,  the EXPORT DATA statement doesn’t support Single URI.

You can use the bq extract [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) to export the BQ table.

```
bq --location=location extract \
--destination_format format \
--compression compression_type \
--field_delimiter delimiter \
--print_header=boolean \
project_id:dataset.table \
gs://bucket/filename.ext
```

In fact bq extract should not have the empty file issue like the EXPORT DATA statement even when you use Wildcard URI.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same empty files issue when using EXPORT DATA.

After doing a bit of R&D found the solution. Put LIMIT xxx in your SELECT SQL and it will do the trick.

You can find the count, and put that as LIMIT value.

SELECT ....

FROM ...

WHERE ...

**LIMIT xxx**

Comment: In my case the results were well under 1000 rows but still created multiple files, adding limit 1000 solved this.

Comment: Rather than pre-counting the rows (double billing) you may add `LIMIT 9223372036854775807`, it will work in all cases... But if your extraction is big the query will take forever

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, and adding ORDER BY limited the results to be written into 1 file.
SELECT col1, col2 from
TABLE
WHERE CONDITION
ORDER BY COL1;

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need to enforce multiple files, wildcard syntax. Either a file for CSV or folder for other like AVRO.

> The uri option must be a single-wildcard URI as described

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements

Comment: Thank you @pentium10 for responding. I tried removing "*" but I get an error "Invalid uri specification. option "uri" value must be a valid wild card URI.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a wildcard seems to start several workers to work on the extract, and as per the documentation, `size of the exported files will vary`.

Zero-length files is unusual but technically possible if the first worker is done before any other really get started. Hence why the wildcard is expected to be used only when `you think your exported data will be larger than the 1 GB`

I have just faced the same with Parquet but found out that bq CLI works, which should do for any format.

See (and star for traction) https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/181016197