# BigQuery EXPORT sql is sharding small query results

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, export

I have a partitioned table with less than `600MB` data in the targeted partitions.

When I run an `EXPORT` query with a subquery that returns `~1000 rows`, `EXPORT` shards the data into 27(!) files.

This is not a big query result. I assume it's happening because the optimizer sees the `600MB`, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone else encountered this? I am GZIPing the results so concatenating would involve unzipping, appending and zipping again...

Comment: Could you provide more information how did you exported this? Did you use API, CLI, UI? I've tested one global partitioned table `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_global_population.population_by_country` ~200 records and I have only one file. What Export format did you chose? Where did you export this?

Comment: I did use the API and UI with the same query statement. It's a table in my own project. The table is partitioned and I suspect maybe that's what is causing it. Creating a temp table with the subquery and then exporting using the temp table has solved this - however it's peculiar that the table shards the result from the original table itself...

Comment: So your solution is enough or you are still looking for different solution? If you would try different table in different dataset, output is the same (you are getting more files) ?

Comment: The solution I have works, but it seems to me that this doesn't align with what Google says is supposed to happen. Sharding is supposed to happen at 1GB (I vaguely remember reading that). Well I just ran it on a different table ~700mb in size and, again, it sharded it into 27! different compressed files. If I create a temp table with the query result and instead EXPORT DATA from this table, it seems to minimize shards, but on occasion still splits it into 2-3 shards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run many various export scenarios in `BigQuery`. I think there is only one use case when `BigQuery export` would export multiple files where `Table size` is `partitioned` and smaller than **1 GB**. It's using [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) during exporting.

> BigQuery supports a single wildcard operator (*) in each URI. The wildcard can appear anywhere in the URI except as part of the bucket name. Using the wildcard operator instructs BigQuery to create multiple sharded files based on the supplied pattern.

I have tested this on using `Public database` with partitioned and normal table:

- Partitioned table: `bigquery-public-data.covid19_geotab_mobility_impact.us_border_wait_times`
- Normal table: `bigquery-public-data.covid19_google_mobility.mobility_report`

**Scenario 1:**

Normal table: `bigquery-public-data.covid19_google_mobility.mobility_report`

```
Table size - 771.81 MB
Number of rows - 7,254,927
```

When I exported this normally (using GZIP) I've got only one file (regularexportnowildcard). When I used `wildcard` it created 2 files with the same size (`regularexport000000000000` and `regularexport000000000001`).

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

Partitioned table: `bigquery-public-data.covid19_geotab_mobility_impact.us_border_wait_times`

```
Table size - 540.25 MB
Number of rows - 870,064
```

When I have exported a Partitioned table normally, without a wildcard I've got only one file (`nowildcardexport`).
**However**, when I tried to export `Partitioned Table` with `Wildcards`, I got 586 files as a result.

[image: <screen 2>]
[image: <screen 3>]

As stated in the GCP Documentation [Introduction to partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables)

> A partitioned table is a special table that is divided into segments, called partitions, that make it easier to manage and query your data. By dividing a large table into smaller partitions, you can improve query performance, and you can control costs by reducing the number of bytes read by a query.

It looks like, if you are using `wildcards` with `partitioned table`, it creates each file for each partition in the table.

**UPDATE**

When you are using [EXPORT DATA statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement) you have to use wildcard otherwise you will get an error:

```
Invalid uri specification. Option 'uri' value must be a wild card URI.
```

As workaround of this, you could try to use `UI` or `bq` command. More details can be found in [this Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181016197)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. How did you export the data without a wildcard in the destination URI? EXPORT DATA query statement does not allow non wildcard URIs - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements it says it must be a single wildcard URI ...?

Comment: I have used GCP UI, not Export Query. As stated in the documentation you have share, when you are using `EXPORT DATA OPTIONS` URI must be wildcard. However, as workaround you can use `bq` command or use User Interface. There was already a Issue Tracker for this behavior, which can be fund [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181016197)

Answer (score 0):

As a cross reference - the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388650/4985705 by nicolas noziere

> Add a `select distinct *`  to force all data to be loaded into one worker.

results in one single file.