# GCP Export Data Options gives Option 'uri' value must be a wild card URI

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, export-to-csv

I am trying to export query output to a file in cloud storage.
The query output is always <1GB but the export data options is creating multiple smaller files.
Example:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
      uri='gs://test_bucket/test_file_*.csv',
      format='CSV',
      overwrite=true,
      header=true,
      field_delimiter=';') AS
    SELECT * FROM `test.test_table`;
```

When I provide filename without a wildcard (gs://test_bucket/test_file_1.csv), i see an error "Invalid uri specification. Option 'uri' value must be a wild card URI."

Is there anyway to generate only ONE file always using export data options?

Comment: The uri option must be a single-wildcard URI : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_option_list

Comment: Try loading data to a table and then export it to GCS. It may result into single file.

Comment: @Mr.Batra The queries can be dynamic including aggregate queries, loading to the table needs a new destination table to be created every time a query is run.

Answer (score 1):

Cross reference: the code

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://test_bucket/test_file_*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `test.test_table`;
```

as answered by nicolas noziere https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388650/4985705  (add distinct to force all data to be loaded into one worker.) generates only ONE file always using export data options.