# Bigquery: Export Data Option, Multiple Files

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, extract

Some days ago, I had a question about a query using EXPORT DATA OPTIONS in BIGQUERY. In the end, the query that was produced is the following:

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket_1/folder_1/final_file_'|| format_date('%Y%m%d', current_date()) || '*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';'
  
      ) AS
select * from `table_1`
```

Consider that Table_1 has 60079 rows/20 columns and the result is a single csv file, Which is what I want.

Then, I try the same query but with "table_2", which has 982 rows/9 columns; it doesn't produce a single file, but instead, it produces 41 files, and I don´t understand why with one table it works and with the other one it doesn´t.

Thank you For your help

Comment: Hello, Just in case I found a solution, which I don`t know if it is permanent or not, it involves using a limit and the then of the select. This is shown here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045942/big-query-export-data-statement-creating-mutiple-files-with-no-data-and-just-hea

Comment: As the above comments suggests you just need to add "select distinct * ..." but i have tried that and it doesn't work. I'm keen to solve this issue too. let me know if 'distinct' works in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into the answers in some of the similar questions, It appears that is the intended behaviour as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data).

> The size of the exported files will vary

Also adding LIMIT to the query works for others, But another alternative is using CLI to export. See reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data).

Sample Code(found in the reference):

```
bq extract --location=location \
--destination_format format \
--compression compression_type \
--field_delimiter delimiter \
--print_header=boolean \
project_id:dataset.table \
gs://bucket/filename.ext
```